# Removing symbol from all Keys in Dictionary

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary, data-cleaning

I know this is simple, but I just can't figure it out. I have a bunch of keys in a dictionary, a large portion of which end with `"*"`. I want to keep those keys but remove the asterisk.

```
for key, value in network.items():
        if key.endswith('*'):
            network[key.replace("*", "")] = network.pop(key)
```

The code runs, but the asterisks remain! Any insights as to why this is happening?

Comment: You cannot add or delete keys while iterating through a dictionary.  The result is undefined.  Your best bet is `network = {key.replace("*", ""): value for key, value in network.items()} which builds a new dictionary.

Comment: You are modifying the dict while iterating over it. Try `for key, value in list(network.items())` if the dict isn't too large.

Comment: @PM77-1.  The `pop()` is removing the old keys.  That's not what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) and dict comprehension like so:

```
import re
network = {'k1': 'v1', 'k2*': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3', 'k4*': 'v4'}
network = {re.sub(r'[*]$', '', k): v for (k, v) in network.items()}
print(network)
# {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3', 'k4': 'v4'}
```